# ServerSocket issue to stop thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, proxy

I'm implementing a proxy using sockets and I need to stop/start the ServerSocket when required, the problem is that I'm executing the server as a thread and I don't know how to stop it once the thread is running...

Edit, new code:

```
    public void startServer() throws IOException {

    final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(getPORT());
                serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
                while (process) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have something to break out of your loop - the `process` variable. You should be able to exit out of the loop by setting the `process` variable to `false`.
However, if no connection is made to the socket, serverSocket.accept() will block for ever. So you should expose a method to close the serverSocket. Please see code below:

class Server {

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private boolean process = true;

public void startServer() throws IOException {

    final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(getPORT());
                serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
                Server.this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
                while (process) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();
}

public void closeServer() {
    this.process = false;
    if (this.serverSocket != null) {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //ignore
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}